# Does Device admin deprecation means that we will no longer be able to disable camera?

Tags: android, android-camera

As Android [Device Administration](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html) is going to be [deprecated](https://developers.google.com/android/work/device-admin-deprecation). It will be replaced with [Android Enterprise Mobility Manager(EMM)](https://developers.google.com/android/work/requirements), and as shown in the [feature list](https://developers.google.com/android/work/requirements/features) disabling of camera is not supported in work profile. Work managed device would require a factory reset in order to setup.

So will we no longer be able to disable cameras for BYOD? Or are there other methods to disable camera for all profiles/entire device like Samsung KNOX does?

Answer (score 0):

yes the API will be deprecated but your app will not break if you are targeting older version of Android e.g.

```
targetSdkVersion 25
```

Answer (score 0):

Work profile is not a solution as it will disable camera only for apps under this profile and not for personal apps.

You should use the legacy mode with old sdk and Google may prevent you to publish updates at Play store.

I think that BYOD will be a real issue at Android 10.